# Spring Tool can't create the java virtual machine

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I'm having problems executing Spring Tool, I get the error: Could not create the java virtual machine, and this in another window:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message isn't really explaining in detail what the problem is, but I would recommend to things here:

- update to a recent JDK 1.8.0 (I think it is at 1.8.0_181 at the moment) and use that.
- you can also specify the JVM to run STS in the STS.ini file in the same way than you could do that for plain Eclipse in the eclipse.ini file (described in more detail here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

It also looks like you are running a 64bit operating system, so in case you have a 64bit JDK installed, you should make sure to download and use the 64bit version of STS. From the error dialog it looks like you are trying to use the 32bit version of STS. You can do that, if you want to, but you would need to make sure that it picks up a 32bit JDK then. But I would strongly recommend to use a 64bit JDK together with the 64bit version of STS.

Answer (score 0):

You better use JDK 1.8 etc. 1.6 is so old for starting new STS